# Pick a number from two columns and calculate

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, fstream, calculated-columns

A given file contains pairs of `<two-digit number, amount>`.  Then take a toss-up two-digit number (called X), and compute the win/loss amount.  The win/loss rule is if the input number matches X, then it’s a win and the winning total is (amount * 70); otherwise, it’s a loss of (-amount).

> `For example: [ticket.txt] 
>   09 10 
>   13 15 
>   25 21`

If the toss-up number is 09, the win/loss amount of the ticket is (10 * 70 - 15 - 21)

If the toss-up number is 42, the win/loss amount of the ticket is (-10 - 15 - 21).

This is my beginner project. I stuck at calculating the win amount and lost amount.
[This is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQouj.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int line1[100]; // array that can hold 100 numbers for 1st column
int line2[100]; // array that can hold 100 numbers for 2nd column
int main()
{
    int winNum, winAmount, lostAmount;
    int num = 0; // num start at 0
    ifstream inFile; 
    inFile.open("Ticket.txt"); //open File
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Fail to open the file" << endl;      
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Numbers from File: " << endl;
    while (!inFile.eof()) // read File to end of file
        {
            inFile >> line1[num]; // read first column, the first column is the number that user choosing
            inFile >> line2[num]; // read second column, the second column is the amount of money that user paying
            cout << "\n" << line1[num] << "\t" << line2[num];
            ++num; 
        }
    inFile.close();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the toss-up number: "; // enter the win number
    cin >> winNum;
    if (line1[num] == winNum) 
    {
        winAmount = line2[num] * 70; //  number user choose = win number, winAmount = winAmount * 70 - lostAmount
        cout << winAmount;
        }
        else
        {
            lostAmount =- line2[num]; //number user choose != win number, the amount will be -lost amounts
cout << lostAmount;
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see result at the end of the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int line1[100]; // array that can hold 100 numbers for 1st column
int line2[100]; // array that can hold 100 numbers for 2nd column
int main()
{
    int winNum, winAmount = 0, lostAmount = 0, result = 0;
    int num = 0; // num start at 0
    ifstream inFile; 
    ifstream inFile2; 
    int rowNumber = 0;
    string line;
    inFile.open("Ticket.txt"); //open File
    inFile2.open("Ticket.txt");
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Fail to open the file" << endl;      
        return 1;
    }

     while (getline(inFile2, line))
        ++rowNumber;
    cout << "Number of lines in text file: " << rowNumber << "\n";


    int myArray[rowNumber][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            inFile >> myArray[i][j];

    cout << "Numbers from File: " << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)   
        {
            cout << myArray[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";       
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the toss-up number: "; // enter the win number
    cin >> winNum;

    for(int i = 0; i< rowNumber; i++)
    {
        if (myArray[i][0] == winNum) 
        {
            winAmount = myArray[i][1] * 70; //  number user choose = win number, winAmount = winAmount * 70 - lostAmount
        }
        else
        {
            lostAmount = lostAmount + myArray[i][1]; //number user choose != win number, the amount will be -lost amounts
        }
    }

    result = winAmount - lostAmount;
    cout << result;

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you code, but it had some small problem at the end. For example, If I choose 09 is the toss-up number, winAmount = 10*70-15-21 = 664, instead of 700-15-21. It also had problem if the toss-up number is 13, the result will print out -101050-21. Moreover, what if the file has more than 3 number in the same column. Do you know to fix these problems?

Comment: The code was edited. I think it will help you :) @TranNguyen

Comment: I greatly appreciate for your help. Now I'm trying to figure out how to make the code read more than 3 numbers in the same column. Do you know how to make it? Also, can you make some notes for the code?

Comment: What do you mean more than 3 numbers ? Is it specific like 15 number ?

Comment: While reading file by arrays have a fixed size. Can we use vector to read a file? What I mean is that what if the file `ticket.txt` doesn't have specific size

Comment: Get the file's rows number and assign it to rowNumber first . Then define array like myArray[rowNumber][2]. Don't forget change first loop number with rowNumber. Is it what you want ?

Comment: Code was updated again. You can get rowNumber, when you run the program.

Answer (score 0):

When you test `line1[num] == winNum` (and all the operations carried out after that) you're using the value of `num` that you modified with `++num;`, this means you're working with empty or not meaningful values for both `line1` and `line2`. For example, if the 3 rows of values showed in your "ticket.txt" are used, they are stored in postions 0, 1 and 2 of the arrays, while the `num` has a value of 4 at the end.

If I understood what you are trying to achieve, you should put the if-else statement in a for loop that goes from 0 to `num`, and then every operation on `line1` and `line2` should be done with the looping variable as an index.
Also, move the `cout` just after the loop if you want only total amounts to be displayed.